# Sidebar scroll is not working. Only page scroll is working

Tags: html, css

I am designing a webpage in which I have a sidebar and some other stuff like shown below

[image]

Here, **Your Friends** is the sidebar I am talking about. whenever I put my cursor over that sidebar and scroll, the page is scrolling instead of the sidebar.

What I am expecting to happen is that, when I put my cursor outside of that sidebar and scroll, the main page should scroll down. and when I keep it on the sidebar and scroll the sidebar should scroll down.

This is the CSS of my sidebar

```
header .c-header-container .c-side-bar-right {
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  bottom: 37px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: var(--side-bar-color);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 4px solid black;
  border-top: none;
  width: 20%;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really see no flaw in your codes but could you please try setting the z-index to a positive value or better still remove it?
Relative to which element did you set the z-index and what are the css properties of this element?.. We're still working

Comment: The gear icon in the navbar at the top is a dropdown. without the z-index, this sidebar is overlapping with its dropdown. So I included that property.

Comment: Hey if I remove the z-index in the sidebar. the scroll functionality is working as per my requirement. but I cannot see the dropdown from gear.

Comment: @UmakanthPendyala can you try setting a positive z-index to the top navigation bar instead?

Comment: Yeah, I kept the z-index of nav to positive and removed the z-index of the sidebar. it worked. Thank you

Comment: May the spirit be with you.

Answer (score 1):

The sidebar isn't scrolling probably because of its **z-index**. Try setting it to high value, maybe 99 or more. This should fix the problem.

```css
.sidebar-class {
    z-index: 99;
}
```